# Is there a way to replace empty cells with a particular value in its duplicate rows?

Tags: r

I have the following data frame

```
     Name Product Unit Class
2  sushil   seeds           
4   sanju    Soap   46     C
5   rahul            5      
7   sanju            4     E
9  sushil           20     B
10  rahul    Soap          A
```

and what I need is, a data frame without duplicate rows with the below conditions.

1. if the row is having all columns values filled then eliminate the second duplicate row.
2. if the row is having few of the columns value empty then replace the empty cell with the similar column values from its duplicate row.

The desired result should look like this.

```
   Name Product Unit Class
1 sushil   seeds   20     B
2  sanju    Soap   46     C
3  rahul    Soap    5     A
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

here is the df code.

```
Name <- c("abbas","sushil","abbas","sanju","rahul","shweta","sanju","rajiv","sushil","rahul")
Unit <- c(18," ",18,46,5,67,4,3,20," ")
Product <- c("Rice","seeds","Rice","Soap"," ","Towel"," "," "," ","Soap")
Class <- c("A"," ","A","C"," ","D","E","A","B","A")

Data <- data.frame(Name,Product,Unit,Class)
duplicate <- which(duplicated(Data))
unique <- Data[!duplicated(Data),] 

NewData <- unique[unique$Name %in% unique$Name[duplicated(unique$Name)],]
```

Comment: Hi David Arenbug, thanks for the edit.

Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: I have added the d code that I used. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following I am assuming that the primary ID is the Name column.

First part (harder):

```
library(tidyverse)
df[ df == "" ] <- NA
df2 <- df %>% 
   mutate(complete=complete.cases(df)) %>% 
   group_by(Name) %>% 
   mutate(any_complete=any(complete)) %>% 
   filter( complete | (!complete & !any_complete)) %>%
   select(-complete, -any_complete)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   Name [3]
  Name   Product  Unit Class
  <chr>  <chr>   <int> <chr>
1 sushil seeds      NA NA   
2 sanju  Soap       46 C    
3 rahul  NA          5 NA   
4 sushil NA         20 B    
5 rahul  Soap       NA A
```

Explanation: first we replace all missing strings by actual NA's. Then, we create a column, `complete`, which checks whether all of the columns are complete for a given row. Next we create another column that tells us whether, for any given `Name` there is a complete observation. Finally, we keep only the rows which are either (i) complete or (ii) not complete, but a complete observation for that Name is missing.

Second task is simpler, but boring:

```
df2 %>% arrange(Name, Product) %>% fill(Product) %>%
        arrange(Name, Unit) %>% fill(Unit) %>%
        arrange(Name, Class) %>% fill(Class) %>% 
        filter(!duplicated(Name))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   Name [3]
  Name   Product  Unit Class
  <chr>  <chr>   <int> <chr>
1 rahul  Soap        5 A    
2 sanju  Soap       46 C    
3 sushil seeds      20 B
```